# iPhone app running in Instruments fails with unrecognized selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, instruments

I have an app that appears to run without problems in normal use.  The Clang Static Analyzer reports no problems either.  When I try to run it in Instruments, it fails with an unrecognized selector exception.

The offending line is a simple property setter of the form:

```
self.bar = baz;
```

To figure out what's going on, I added an NSLog() call immediately above it:

```
NSLog(@"class = %@ responds = %d", [self class], [self respondsToSelector:@selector(setBar:)]);
self.bar = baz;
```

On the emulator (without Instruments) and on a device, this shows exactly what I'd expect:

class = Foo responds = 1

When running under Instruments, I get:

class = Foo responds = 0

I'm stumped as to what could cause this.  Perhaps a different memory location is getting tromped on when it's in the Instruments environment?  Can anyone suggest how I might debug this?

Answer (score 0):

If bar belongs to self, can't you do `bar=baz;` ?

Comment: That won't notify any observers of the property, and it's possible that bar isn't even directly implemented as an instance variable.  It may be synthesized from other values. For example, a "fullname" property could be stored in the "firstname" and "lastname" ivars and not have any ivar directly backing it up.

Answer (score 0):

Check your properties.
Perhaps to you need a cast on baz?

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information here to know what's going on, but then, if you knew what information to provide you'd probably have already fixed it.  So.  A few things to check:

- Is the "self" pointer being swizzled in any way?  Try printing out the value of `self` at various points just for sanity's sake
- When your code runs in Instruments, is it running in a different mode?  (32-bit vs. 64-bit, Garbage collected vs. Retain-Release, etc.)  I'm not sure why any of those would have an effect, but if it's running in a different mode, that's something to look into.
- Are you synthesizing the setter correctly?  Or is it being provided dynamically (via Core Data, etc.)? If you manually specify a `setBar:` method, do you still get the error?